# how to snmpset string or integer value with python?

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp

I'm trying to set value with snmpset via python.

```
import netsnmp
snmpcfgfile=netsnmp.Varbind(".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.12.1.2.18.1.1.5.3", 
                            "switch.cfg","STRING")
netsnmp.snmpset(snmpcfgfile, Version=2, DestHost="10.0.112.4", Community="public")`
```

(2 second later i see an error): TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found

And value is not changed.

What do I do wrong? how should I make it correct?

trace (please help to understand what it means):

```
--Call--
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py(185)set()
-> def set(self, varlist):
(Pdb)
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py(186)set()
-> res = client_intf.set(self, varlist)
(Pdb)
--Call--
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py(94)__iter__()
-> def __iter__(self):
(Pdb)
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py(95)__iter__()
-> return iter(self.varbinds)
(Pdb)
--Return--
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py(95)__iter__()-><listite...c8096490>
-> return iter(self.varbinds)
(Pdb)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./snmp-set.py", line 7, in <module>
    netsnmp.snmpset(snmpcfgfile, Version=2, DestHost="10.0.112.4", Community="public")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py", line 228, in snmpset
    res = sess.set(var_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py", line 187, in set
    return res
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py", line 187, in set
    return res
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 67, in dispatch_line
    self.user_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 157, in user_line
    if self.bp_commands(frame):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 167, in bp_commands
    if getattr(self, "currentbp", False) and \
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Comment: Show us the complete code.

Comment: @m170897017 I've edited question. look at it. There is a whole code in the question

Comment: 2 seconds delay looks like the requests are timing out. Are you sure that 'public' should be used as a community string?

Comment: @pajaja Yes, i'm sure. if i do with bash then all ok.

Comment: Snoop your traffic using Wireshark or similar, then you can see if your script is sending a valid snmp request. Compare the packet contents with the successful request from bash.

Comment: @Jolta I've checked. It is strange. the python sends no data at all.

Comment: There is no 2 seconds latency. I receive the error after the second "Enter". I type the command press "Enter" and see ">>>". after I press "Enter" again I receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow advice from [this blog post](http://blog.ar-ix.net/archives/9), and decompose your OID in a string and index this way:

```
snmpcfgfile=netsnmp.Varbind("agentBscSwFile", "0", "switch.cfg", "STRING")
```

You should also make sure that you can write OIDs with the "public" community, usually this community defaults to read-only in default factory settings.

Good luck, documentation on net-snmp python bindings is spotty at best.